# NSDate object crashing when calling dateByAddingTimeInterval: function. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have declared an NSDate object in .h part. In .m, in viedDidLoad, I used the following lines and it's working fine

```
shownDate = [NSDate date];
shownDate = [shownDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400.0];
```

Then when i click a button, I call the same function inside a function

```
    shownDate = [shownDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400.0];
```

But here it's crashing. These are the only 3 lines in the program where I have used this function.  Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how you are calling it.  My best guess without more code is that shownDate is autoreleased.  Try retaining it and then releasing it when you no longer need it.

Comment: Yes this was my issue, I had my date as a property with (assign), using (strong) worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain your `shownDate` variable its autoreleased in your case.

instead of

```
shownDate = [NSDate date];
```

use

```
shownDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
shownDate = [NSDate date];
shownDate = [shownDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400.0];
[shownDate retain];
```

When called from button click:

```
NSDate newDate = [shownDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400.0];
[shownDate release];
shownDate = newDate;
[shownDate retain];
```

alternatively make shownDate a retain property and refer to it as self.shownDate and the retain/release will be handled automatically.